# Swift dictionary as property does not init

Tags: swift

I have a class which has a swift dictionary as internal variable.

```
   class OAuth: NSObject {

    public var oauthParameters:[String:String]
    public var SignatureSecret:String

    public var accessToken:String? = nil
    public var tokenSecret: String? = nil

    public init(consumerKey:String, consumerSecret:String, accessToken:String?, tokensecret:String?){

        self.oauthParameters = ["oauth_signature_method" : "SHA1"]

        if accessToken{
            self.oauthParameters.updateValue(accessToken!, forKey: "oauth_token")
        }

        if tokensecret{
            self.SignatureSecret = "\(consumerSecret)&\(tokensecret!)"
        }
        else {
            self.SignatureSecret = "\(consumerSecret)&"
        }

    }
}
```

I would like to assign some keys of the dictionary in function of the passed arguments, but the problem is that the variable `oauthParameters`does not retain the values passed as literals :(

**EDIT:** I guessed the dictionary was not initialzed because LLDB printed me out an empty dictionary (Xcode6B4) wehereas a println confirms all were ok.

Comment: You should also call `super.init`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your initializer isn't complete. For some reason the Playground isn't giving me an actual error, but you need to give `self.SignatureSecret` a value before exiting `init()`:

```
public init(consumerKey:String, consumerSecret:String, accessToken:String?, tokensecret:String?)
{
    self.oauthParameters = ["oauth_signature_method" : "SHA1"]
    self.SignatureSecret = String()
}
```

Once that's fixed I can see the values in `self.oauthParameters`:

```
println(o.oauthParameters["oauth_signature_method"]!)
// prints "SHA1"
```

Comment: The problem did not come from the code (I complete It). It is LLDB that were giving me an empty dictionary

Comment: To me it looks like your code is working the way it should - the values are stored in the dictionary properly and can be accessed without any trouble. Are you not finding them when trying to access them later? You could either be (a) not understanding what LLDB is telling you or (b) looking at a Xcode bug.

Answer (score 1):

It loos like you need to initialize `oauthParameters`
try something like this:

```
public var oauthParameters: [String: String] = [String: String]()
```